# Angular js dependency declaration alternative

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I know I can declare a dependency in angular doing:

```
var app = angular.module('ourApp', ['ngTagsInput']);
```

Which works great. Is there another place/way I can do dependency declaration in angular?

I want to do the above but I only want the dependency for a particular partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple modules within your app but you need to manually bootstrap anything beyond the first ng-app.  That said there's still no mechanism built into angular for lazy/deferred loading of modules so you'd need to handle that yourself.